# Marmalade s3eAudio not playing on windows build

Tags: marmalade, build-environment

I'm building a multiplatform application, when we build for windows the audio only works on the PC that builds it. When we build for tablets all sounds work, when we build for PC it is only the audio that isnt playing, soundeffects (s3eSound ) is working fine.

The sound paths we use are relative ( data / sounds ).

Is there something windows specific I need to be aware of, or does anyone have any ideas about where I can start looking?

Thanks,

Line

Comment: So which is your target platform? Tablet or PC?

Comment: Both are :) Adding stuff to reach min char limit

Comment: Well I don't think Marmalade supports desktop apps, unless it's windows 8 app. Is it?

Comment: they do - http://www.madewithmarmalade.com/marmaladesdk/supported-platforms

Comment: Ahh thanks. Never built any submission app for windows, except debug ones. Check my answer btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue must be some path issue. The sound file is not available to marmalade on specified location. So it'd be the most probable reason. Another pitfall I can imagine is you're not making a build which includes the bin files(group.bin files). Thus the app could not locate the sound (which should be in the bin file).

You need to select proper asset group in deploy tool, if it's the case.

Comment: Just a note to others reading this answer to clarify what was my specific problem:

The problem I had was that I had music in a folder called music and sound effects in a folder called sounds. Had correct paths in code, but still didn't work. When i moved the music in to the "sounds" folder and ammended the code it worked. Sounds might be a default folder, I don't know - just happy it works :)

Comment: Thanks for providing the clarification. Should be helpful for users.